# Message oversized on WCF communication

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a windows service and a winform application that communicate between each other using WCF through TCP.

I sometimes have to exchange huge data and I encountered a `CommunicationException` on the client. Now I have trouble finding which property to change and where (on the server side or the client side?).

The problem occurs when the server is returning a value to the client that is a `2-uple` (my own implementation) of two arrays of doubles: `Tuple<Double[], Double[]>` (both arrays have always the same length).
I have noticed that there is no error when the arrays have a length of `22 000`, but the `CommunicationException` is thrown when arrays have a length of `44 000`.

Here's my `App.config` file regarding the `netTcpBinding` part:

- On the server:

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBindingConf"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"
                      maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
        <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

- On the client:

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBindingConf"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000"
             sendTimeout="00:59:00">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"
                      maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
        <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

Could you point on which property to change and on which side?

*P.S:* It's not a timeout problem.

---

## EDIT

I have now the same `nettcpbinding`configuration on both server and client:

```
<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBindingConf" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 sendTimeout="00:30:00">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                          maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                          maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                          maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                          maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And the same `serviceBehavior`:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Debug">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I then get a `NetDispatcherFaultException` on the client, advising me to increase `maxArrayLength` or `maxItemsInObjectGraph`. But for me, these values are already largely set for what I need to transfer and also set to the max values!

Here's the `InnerException` message:

> The maximum array length quota (19502) or the maximum items in object graph quota has been exceeded while reading XML data. These quotas may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas or the MaxItemsInObjectGraph setting.

Any clue? Where does this `19 502` figure comes from?

Comment: Do you have your <readerQuotas/> set on both the client and server side?

Comment: @ChrisNel52: I updated the Q, on both.

Comment: @Otiel - Are you referencing the bindings you configured in your endpoint with the bindingConfiguration attribute?  If you're not, you'll get the default values for the binding, not the ones you set and expected.

Comment: @Tim: Yes I am : `<endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindingConf" contract="blah blah" name="blah blah" />`

Comment: @Otiel Is this open question again ? with bounty ? if yes the what is your new issue now :)

Comment: @SurjitSamra: The *why* is in the bounty description : "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty." I want to offer a bounty to Gabobcat for his help, but I have to wait 24 hours before being able to award it. Thanks for checking in though :)

Comment: Would you be open to options involving changing the serializer? (can be done inside WCF via config-file changes). This would usually result in much less bandwidth, too..

Comment: @MarcGravell: My problem is already solved, I opened the bounty only to reward an existing answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: k; cheers for the update

Comment: and proto buf will be Marc's first choice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On both, the server and client you have to configure the  attribute of your binding, if you are exchanging large amounts of data between them. For example:

```
<binding name="LargeSettings" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
```

Work your way from the large values to find the one that suits you.

EDIT:

In Client side, you need to configure a behavior, and set that behavior in the client endpoint. Something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="debug"> <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

And you set the behavior in the client endpoint:

```
<endpoint name="myEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="debug">
    Your other settings...
</endpoint>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please post the full exception details? Maybe there is something we are missing.

Comment: I updated my question with the new error I'm getting. Please see my edit.

Comment: Are you sure your binding is correctly mapped on both server and client? Is your service tag referencing the <behavior name="Debug"> behavior? like in <service behaviorConfiguration="Debug">?

Comment: Yes. Although I only have `<service>` configurations on my server, and only `<client>` configurations on my client.

Comment: I am not sure if this is going to help you. In the client side, you need to configure a behavior, and set that behavior in the client endpoint. Something like this: <system.serviceModel> <behaviors> <endpointBehaviors> <behavior name="debug"> <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" /> </behavior> </endpointBehaviors> </behaviors> And you set the behavior in the client endpoint: <endpoint name="myEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="debug"> Your other settings... </endpoint>.

Comment: Oh yes, this is helping me! I found the problem: I did not have any `<endpointBehaviors>` on my client. Now it works great. Thanks a lot for the help, I feel like I should award you a bounty. (:

Comment: I will update my answer with that last part. Just accept it and I'll be happy :P Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would increase the `MaxReceivedMessageSize`, ensuring that `maxBufferSize` is also adjusted. These are the common areas that we have needed to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a copy of a wsHttpBinding that I haved used in tests to successfully transfer huge chunks of data. I'm not saying these values are best practices, but they work to pass big chunks of data.

```
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_LargeData" 
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
      maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999">

      <readerQuotas 
         maxDepth="128" 
         maxStringContentLength="8192" 
         maxArrayLength="163840000" 
         maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
         maxNameTableCharCount="16384"
      />
    </binding>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try maxItemsInObjectGraph in your service behavior

```
 <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
```

Comment: I still have the same `NetDispatcherFaultException`.

Comment: upload your sample project somewhere and let me know , I have so many this kind of errors when i migrated my finance back office from 10 old .net remoting to WCF :)

Comment: I found the answer thanks to **Gabobcat**. Thanks for your help and your time though! The `maxItemsInObjectGraph` property was the one to change.

Comment: when you said in your edited question that you got same configs on both client and server , I assumed you have same maxItemsInObjectGraph setting in at server and client side. Any way its good you got it sorted and I was helpful :)